# The validation mechanism of asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, c#-4.0

I wonder that, what is the process of the validation mechanism in asp.net?
When I donot enter anything in the textboxes, the error messages come but which I wonder the mechanism of it, which attribute triggers it?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
Your name:<br />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtName" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="reqName" controltovalidate="txtName" errormessage="Please enter your name!" />
<br /><br />
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnSubmitForm" text="Ok" />
```

which mechanism supplies the control in asp.net?

Comment: too generic. Please show some code, the aspx page and the .cs code so we can see what you are talking about :)

Answer (score 0):

You should search the documentation about the `RequiredFieldValidator` control.

I am convinced that control is working checking the content of the linked control (specified by id in the `controltovalidate` attribute) and rendering the error in case the control fails to validate.

what other details would you like to know?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I found what I look for;
via post mechanism, everything is sent, you can see via using firebug.

Answer (score 0):

When you use required field validators, JavaScript methods are added to the page. You can see how the validators work by looking at the page source:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
    if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) return false;
    return true;
    }
    //]]>

</script>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //<![CDATA[
    var Page_Validators =  new Array(document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentBody_reqBilledDate"), document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentBody_reqInvoiceNumber"), document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentBody_reqBillingMethod"));
    //]]>

</script>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var Page_ValidationActive = false;
    if (typeof(ValidatorOnLoad) == "function") {
        ValidatorOnLoad();
    }

    function ValidatorOnSubmit() {
        if (Page_ValidationActive) {
            return ValidatorCommonOnSubmit();
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: thank you James for your helpfully answer. When I view the page source, these are not placed.

Comment: You're viewing the source from the browser, right? And you're not using a Wizard or a multipage or anything, right? I actually copied this from the source of one of our pages.